# Read .html#XXX and display it on a webbrowser

Tags: c#, html

I'm readind html files in local, but these ".html" files are divided internally that have the forme "file.html#xxxxx".
I'm displaying these files on a webbrowser, but it dont accept the path given because of the "#"

I'm reading an epub book, its chapters are divided internally by the "#", after parse i get for each chapter it's own partition and this partition is indicated by #.

this is an exemple of division

```
<navMap>
    <navPoint id="np-1" playOrder="1">
      <navLabel>
        <text>YOUR NATIONAL PARKS BY ENOS A. MILLS</text>
      </navLabel>
      <content src="@public@vhost@g@gutenberg@html@files@42248@42248-h@42248-h-0.htm.html#pgepubid00000"/>
      <navPoint id="np-2" playOrder="2">
        <navLabel>
          <text>PREFACE</text>
        </navLabel>
        <content src="@public@vhost@g@gutenberg@html@files@42248@42248-h@42248-h-0.htm.html#pgepubid00001"/>
      </navPoint>
      <navPoint id="np-3" playOrder="3">
        <navLabel>
          <text>CONTENTS</text>
        </navLabel>
        <content src="@public@vhost@g@gutenberg@html@files@42248@42248-h@42248-h-0.htm.html#pgepubid00002"/>
      </navPoint>
</navMap>
```

and to display:

```
  navPoint = toc.NavMap[0];
 string srcContent = navP.Src;
    webBrowser1.Source= path+srcContent
```

Comment: It is very unclear what the issue you have is. What are you trying to display, where, and what isn't working?

Comment: I want to display the partial content of the html indicaed by the #

Comment: What have you tried? What did you use to parse the HTML? In general, I wouldn't think this was possible, unless the structure of the different sections is similar.

Comment: i'm reading an epub book, its chapitres are divided inrenally by the "#", after parse i get for each chapitre it's own partition and this partition is indicated by #, without the "#" i can display the content but with the "#" visual studio indicate that there is a path error

Comment: You will need to post some code and an example of the HTML/epub structure if you want us to understand what is going on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to keep the answer as clean as possible, so I've completely rewritten the answer. I believe you need to do these steps:

- subscribe to the events called `Navigating` and `DocumentCompleted`
- use the code to parse the url and split it by `#`
- override the navigation and give the WebBrowser the new clean URL without the anchor
- stored the anchor in a variable for instance
- after the document has been loaded, simply find the element referenced by the anchor and scroll to it

The result will probably look like this. Please note this isn't a copy&paste code, I just want to give you an idea how to accomplish what you're after. You need to modify this code to your needs!

Let's say the requested url is `myFile.html#customAnchor`

```
webBrowser1.Navigating += new WebBrowserNavigatingEventHandler(webBrowser1_Navigating);
webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);

private void webBrowser1_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Url.Contains("#")
    {
       string[] urlParts = e.Url.Split('#'); // split the string by character #
       string newUrl = urlParts[0];          // = myFile.html
       _somePrivateField = urlParts[1];      // = customAnchor

       webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri(newUrl));
    }
}

private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    HtmlElementCollection elements = this.webBrowser1.Document.Body.All;
    foreach(HtmlElement element in elements){
       string nameAttribute = element.GetAttribute("Name");
       if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nameAttribute) && nameAttribute == _somePrivateField){
          element.ScrollIntoView(true);
          break;
       }
    }
}
```

Haven't actually tried this, but I hope this will help you enough to solve your problem.

Comment: This is fairly meaningless. And it doesn't really answer the question (where in the HTML would you find these `#` to parse on?).

Comment: @sansa.med, I've just updated the answer.

Comment: @Oded, he's talking about urls, not html itself! Read the question again. It seems he has problems opening urls that end with an "#". Thank's for the -1 tho, you don't understand the question, so you punish others. Good for you.

Comment: what do you mean by "parse everything after it's position"

Comment: @walther - That single line you had was not an answer. That's why I voted the answer down. The update is better, but you will see from [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15534254/read-htmlxxx-and-display-it-on-a-webbrowser/15534300?noredirect=1#comment22007163_15534254) that this is not what the OP needs.

Comment: @sansa.med, please, read my whole answer, try it and explain why it doesn't answer your question. So far your question is a good candidate for closure, you already got one close vote from someone.

Comment: ok, can you explain what your fuction has to do because i can't explain your vision (locate the #)

Comment: @sansa.med, this function takes one parameter (a string), finds the position of `#` (IndexOf) and then outputs the substring starting by position 0 (first character) and ending with position of `#`. In other words, you insert `file.html#someRandomAnchor` and this function returns `file.html`. Never thought I'd have to explain 2 lines of a code like this.

Comment: but i nedd  the "#" because i want to display a part of the file and the begening  of that part is indixateb by the "someRandomAnchor" from the  "file.html#someRandomAnchor"

Comment: @sansa.med, not sure why you've marked my answer as "Accepted" then, but I've taken into account your comments and completely revamped the answer. Please see the result if it finally does what you wanted. If not, I give up.